# 2nd MAX Element is a list

Tags: python

I am trying to find the 2nd max element in a list and I had a question for duplication cases. Why is my for loop not removing all instances of max element in list `2(b)` in list `1(a)`. The for loops should check and remove all instances of duplication. I have attached my code below.

```
a=[]
b=[]
print "Enter the value of n\n"
n= int(raw_input())

print "enter the values\n"

for i in range(0,n):
    y = raw_input()
    a.append(int(y))

max = a[0]
for i in a:
    if max<i:
        max=i
y=max
a.remove(y)
b.append(y)

for q in a:
    for p in b:
        if q==p:
            a.remove(q)

max1 = a[0]
for i in a:
    if  max1<i:
        max1=i

print  max1
```

Output:

```
Enter value of n 
3
enter the values 
32
32
11
ans:11
```

```
Enter value of n 
4
enter the values
32
32
32
32
11
ans:32 (this is wrong)
```

Comment: See [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).  `a.remove(y)` only removes the first instance.  And you should not both iterate the list and remove items from it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you iterate on `a` list, and inside this loop you remove elements of the list. You should not modify a list you are iterating on.

You can use built-in python functions: `set` to remove duplicates, `sorted` to sort

```
>>> a = [32, 32, 32, 32, 11]
>>> sorted(set(a), reverse=True)[1]
11
```

Moreover, you know that Python 2 will soon not me maintained anymore? Change for Python 3 if you can.

Comment: You could improve the runtime and space efficiency by using a max heap

Answer (score 0):

The search of k-th element is a well known problem with a bunch of solutions that can solve it in about O(N) time, please, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Python's standard library (since 2.4) includes `heapq.nsmallest()` and `nlargest()`, returning sorted lists, in O(n log k) time.

Personally, I'd rather use linear O(N) algorithm for your problem:

```
topmost = max( a )    # select the largest one
filtered = [i for i in a if i != topmost]   # filter it out
second_best = max( filtered )   # here you have it!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. As I my new to python can you please explain why you did : filtered=[ i for i in a if i!=topmost] but not filtered=[for i in a if i!=topmost]? for  i in a should be enough for trversing the entire list? thanks

Comment: @SarthakGoyal it's not just traversing the list, it's list comprehension -- creating another list based on the original one. basically, you may rewrite it backwards, `for i in a : if i != topmost : filtered.append(i)` -- but this is longer and harder to grasp. And the first `i` after the `[` is the value that goes into the new list, does not have to be just `i`, can be `i * i` or `exp(2.0, i)` or whatever you like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Below logic may help.

```
    a = []
    print "Enter the value of n\n"
    n= int(raw_input())

    print "enter the values\n"

    for i in range(0,n):
        y = raw_input()
        a.append(int(y))

    # initialise max and second max to negative infinity
    max = float("-inf")
    second_max = float("-inf")

    for i in a:
      # if element is greater than max, set max to greater element and 
      # second max to previous max element.
      if max < i:
        second_max = max
        max = i
      # if the number is between max and second_max, update second_max 
      # only
      elif max > i and second_max < i:
        second_max = i

    print second_max
```

To remove the instances of max element from the list, use:

```
print filter(lambda x: x != max, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, you are iterating over a list and removing item from the same list inside the loop, that will reduce elements from the list and will not work as expected.

The problamatic part is

```
for q in a:
    for p in b:
        if q==p:
            a.remove(q)
```

here you are iterating over list **a** and removing element **a.remove(q)** inside the loop block

So in the first case, 32 32 11 -> It will work fine as it remove 32

but in 2nd case that will not remove the 3rd 32 and you will get [32, 11] in a

Comment: Thank you so much . I had a small question. List b has the max element and the for loops are iterating over both the list and looking for the  max value(that is list 2 value) and removing all the instances of it . so the inner loop will end but the outer loop should check for all instances of list 1? 
So as per you due to indexing as we are deleting and iterating list a same time it fails? Did I understand this correctly? Thanks

Comment: Yes true, suppose if you delete the first item in a list inside the loop, 2nd item will become the first element and since that index(first index) is already covered, that element will not be processed in next iteration.

Comment: Gotcha makes perfect sense now.Thank you so much!

Comment: It can be done simply by,`b = list(set(a))
b.remove(max(b))
max(b)`